# In Cesium, Clipping Planes on tileset was not working

Tags: cesiumjs

When I used Cesium 1.49, I could clipping planes on tileset. But when I updated Cesium to 1.50, it couldn't clipping planes on tileset. How should I do?

```
function clipplanes(dig_point){
console.log(dig_point);
var points = dig_point;

var pointsLength = points.length;

// Create center points for each clipping plane
var clippingPlanes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < pointsLength; ++i) {
    var nextIndex = (i + 1) % pointsLength;
    var midpoint = Cesium.Cartesian3.add(points[i], points[nextIndex], new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    midpoint = Cesium.Cartesian3.multiplyByScalar(midpoint, 0.5, midpoint);
    var up = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(midpoint, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    var right = Cesium.Cartesian3.subtract(points[nextIndex], midpoint, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    right = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(right, right);
    var normal = Cesium.Cartesian3.cross(right, up, new Cesium.Cartesian3());
    normal = Cesium.Cartesian3.normalize(normal, normal);
    // Compute distance by pretending the plane is at the origin
    var originCenteredPlane = new Cesium.Plane(normal, 0.0);
    var distance = Cesium.Plane.getPointDistance(originCenteredPlane, midpoint);
    clippingPlanes.push(new Cesium.ClippingPlane(normal, distance));
}
globe.clippingPlanes = new Cesium.ClippingPlaneCollection({
    planes : clippingPlanes,
    edgeColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
});
//3d tile挖洞
UAVtileset.clippingPlanes = new Cesium.ClippingPlaneCollection({
    planes : clippingPlanes,
    edgeColor: Cesium.Color.WHITE,
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

this is a problem known by developers:

https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/issues/6600

and is also discussed here:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/V3HMRAqToeU

hope this helps.

Comment: Could you tell me what is the relationship between the clip planes and the tile ModelMatrix?  My ModelMatrix is Matrix4.IDENTITY, did it affect the results?

Comment: in my understanding of the theme, the reference system in clipped planes is relative and holds against 3 dimensions being the offset an independent parameter, while in the modelMatrix4 the dimensions you take are 4 and in the case of IDENTITY -> [0,0, 0,0].